# Errors building mysqldb on Mac OS 10.7, Python 2.7.1

Tags: python, macos, mysql-python

I'm trying to build MySQLdb 1.2.3. I've edited the build configuration to set threadsafe = False, and now, when I build, I see the following:

A long list of warnings ala

```
_mysql.c:986: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
```

and an llvm crash at the end:

```
lipo: /var/folders/fk/648y1j5d0c94ljvc5k0xncmh0000gt/T//ccoAI1iz.out and /var/folders/fk/648y1j5d0c94ljvc5k0xncmh0000gt/T//cc9fJKgC.out have the same architectures (x86_64) and can't be in the same fat output file
error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Is there a quick workaround for these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a problem caused by a mismatch between the library version I am building, python version and/or mysql version on my system.

I corrected it by ensuring all versions match at 64 bit, and running

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" python setup.py build
```

as recommended [here](http://learninglamp.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/mysqldb-python-mysql-and-os-x-a-match-made-in-satans-bum/).